# Binding WPF ComboBox to Dictionary<String,ObservableCollection<String>>

Tags: wpf, binding, dictionary, combobox

In my ViewModel, I have a Dictionary of observable string collections, declared as below.

```
public Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<string>> NamePartsDict { get; set; }
```

I would like to bind the Dictionary to ComboBoxes in my user interface in such a way that each ComboBox can 'select' which collection to bind to.

So in my XAML, I would like to use:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" IsEditable="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentLibrary.NamePartsDict[Year]}" Margin="80,0,0.871,0"></ComboBox>
```

which I would expect to bind to the Collection that is indexed by the Key "Year", and populate the ComboBox with the strings stored in the collection.

However, this XAML results in an empty ComboBox.

I have verified that the Dictionary itself can be bound. The below XAML populates the ComboBox with the string representations of each Key, Value pair.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" IsEditable="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentLibrary.NamePartsDict}" Margin="80,0,0.871,0"></ComboBox>
```

Is something in my binding path wrong when obtaining the value from the dictionary? Or am I trying to do something that isn't possible (in which case I'll have to find another way!)?

Any help much appreciated!

Tim

Comment: I just tested this and it works fine for me. Please check if there are really any items in `NamePartsDict[Year]`.

Comment: Yes, there are definitely items there. Well, if it works for you, at least I know it is possible, so I guess I have some debugging to do! Thanks.

Comment: @Clemens I have created a working example with a simple application, and verified that the collection within a dictionary can be bound to. However, I've now also replicated the non-working scenario, which seems to be do to with the fact that my dictionary is a property of an object within the ViewModel, not within the ViewModel itself. So `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Dict[MyCollection2]}` works, where Dict is a property of the ViewModel, but `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DH.Dict[MyCollection2]}` does not work, where DH is a DictionaryHolder class property of the ViewModel.

Comment: @Clemens Have found a solution. This appears to be a Notification problem. When referencing the dictionary alone, I didn't need to explicitly call a PropertyChanged Event to populate the ComboBox. When referencing a collection inside the dictionary, calling the PropertyChanged Event for the dictionary updates the ComboBox. I can't say I fully understand this, but I'm sure there's a good reason!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Datatemplate here
like in here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47923/Using-a-different-DataTemple-when-a-WPF-ComboBox-i

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using a converter:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a 
/// </summary>
public class DomainValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<DomainValue> retVal = null;
        DomainDefinitionCollection dds = value as DomainDefinitionCollection;
        if (dds != null)
        {
            retVal = dds[parameter.ToString()];
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

<controls:ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center"
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
        SelectedValuePath="Value"
        SelectedValue="{Binding ChildClientEntity.EditableEntity.EditableAttributes.TeamPosition, Mode=TwoWay}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ChildClientEntity.Domains, Converter={StaticResource DomainValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=SiteVisitTeamPosition}" />
```

where the ConverterParameter is the key into the dictionary, Domains.

```
public Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<DomainValue>> Domains { get; private set; }
```